# Trouble with Curl and pragma

Tags: curl, libcurl, d, dmd

I'm using `std.net.curl`, so I have to link against libcurl.

Adding `-L-lcurl` works.

However, when I'm adding `pragma(lib,"curl");` at the top of the file importing `std.net.curl`, all sorts of linking errors (missing references) show up.

Why is that? Am I doing anything wrong?

---

Not such a big issue really, but since I do prefer the `pragma` way of linking, I'm actually curious why it's working for e.g. `sqlite3`, but not for Curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pragma(lib)` works best if you compile all the modules together by listing them all on the command line. If you compile them with separate calls to the compiler, the library reference often gets lost (I think the only exception is dmd on Windows).

Are you compiling everything together?

Comment: Yea, for pragma(lib) to work in most cases you need to compile everything together. Which is typically the best way to compile D anyway: it is generally (much) faster and avoids trouble with module import paths too.